# How to change date into name

Tags: php, html, arrays, date

The code below works, but I want to change the months into names, such as "October", "November" and "December" using `MONTHNAME`. When I do, I get an error like the following:

> JulyError in query: unknown column 'July' in 'where clause'.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<body>
 <?php
 $connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die ('unable to connect');
 mysql_select_db("naurah")or die ("cannot select db");

 $query = "SELECT YEAR(date) AS year, SUM(total) AS total FROM `order` GROUP BY year";
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query:".mysql_error());
 if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
     while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
         echo $row[0];
         $query1 = "SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE YEAR(date) = $row[0]";
         $result1=mysql_query($query1) or die ("Error in query:".mysql_error());
         if (mysql_num_rows($result1) > 0) {
             echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tg">
             <strong>
              <tr>
               <th class="tg-031e">Order ID</th>
               <th class="tg-031e" width="100">Date</th>
               <th class="tg-031e">Name</th>
               <th class="tg-031e">Email</th>
               <th class="tg-031e" width="100">Telephone</th>
               <th class="tg-031e">Address</th>
               <th class="tg-031e">City</th>
               <th class="tg-031e">Postcode</th>
               <th class="tg-031e">State</th>
               <th class="tg-031e">Reference No</th>
               <th class="tg-031e">Total</th>
               <th class="tg-031e">Order Status</th>
               <th class="tg-031e">Postage</th>
               <th class="tg-031e">Action</th>
              </tr>
             </strong>';
             while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
                 echo "
                 <tr>
                  <td class=\"tg-4eph\" ><div align=\"center\"> $row1[0] </div></td>
                  <td class=\"tg-031e\" ><div align=\"center\"> $row1[1] </div></td>
                  <td class=\"tg-031e\" ><div align=\"center\">$row1[3] $row1[2]</div></td>
                  <td class=\"tg-4eph\" ><div align=\"center\"> $row1[4]</div></td>
                  <td class=\"tg-031e\" ><div align=\"center\"> $row1[5]</div></td>
                  <td class=\"tg-4eph\" ><div align=\"center\"> $row1[6]</div></td>
                  <td class=\"tg-031e\" ><div align=\"center\"> $row1[7]</div></td>
                  <td class=\"tg-4eph\" ><div align=\"center\"> $row1[8]</div></td>
                  <td class=\"tg-031e\"><div align=\"center\"> $row1[9]</div></td>
                  <td class=\"tg-031e\"><div align=\"center\"> $row1[10]</div></td>
                  <td class=\"tg-031e\"><div align=\"center\"> $row1[11]</div></td>
                  <td class=\"tg-031e\"><div align=\"center\"> $row1[12]</div></td>
                  <td class=\"tg-031e\"><div align=\"center\"> $row1[13]</div></td>
                  <td class=\"tg-4eph\" width=\"100\"><div align=\"center\">                
                   <a href=\"adminupdatetrans.php?orderID= $row1[0]\">
                    <img src=\"../images/icn_edit_article.png\" title=\"Remove\"/>
                   </a>
                   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                   <a href=\"admindeleteorder.php?orderID= $row1[0] \" onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure want to delete ?')\">
                    <img src=\"../images/icn_trash.png\" title=\"Remove\"/>
                   </a>
                  </td>
                 </tr>
                 ";
             }
             echo '
             <tr>
              <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
              <td >Total All:</td>
             ';
             echo '<td>RM';
             echo $row[1];
             echo '</td></tr>';
             echo '</table>';
         }
     }
 }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This much code is unnecessary. Just put your question give 4-5 line of code where you exactly got the error (4-5 line up and 4-5 line down). Put what you expected. and much good if you comment the line where error occurs.

Comment: which date format you are getting

Comment: Improved code readability...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the date is in a timestamp format :),
You can get the names of months thanks to this method :

```
 date("F",mktime(0,0,0,date('m', $timestamp),1,2011));
```

Or like this :

```
 date('F', strtotime("2015-date('m', $timestamp)-01"));
```